# How to get clock accuracy for systemd-timesyncd

Tags: ntp, systemd-timesyncd

I am trying to identify how accurately my clock has been synced using systemd-timesyncd. I ran the following command however there is a lot of information and it isn't abundantly clear what one is the accuracy.

```
% timedatectl timesync-status
       Server: 209.115.181.106 (2.nixos.pool.ntp.org)
Poll interval: 34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
         Leap: normal
      Version: 4
      Stratum: 2
    Reference: CE6C0083
    Precision: 1us (-25)
Root distance: 17.973ms (max: 5s)
       Offset: +7.343ms
        Delay: 57.966ms
       Jitter: 2.767ms
 Packet count: 41
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are what NTP statistics look like. See RFC 5905 about the NTP algorithms, or the [performance page in the NTP docs](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/stats.html).

Approximately, your NTP server is tens of ms away in latency (delay), estimated a bit better than 20 ms offset from the reference clock (root distance). Plus or minus a single digit number of ms (jitter).

That high of latency is pretty obvious this is via the Internet, even before observing the use of the NTP Pool via `2.nixos.pool.ntp.org`.

Think about whether this is acceptable to you. Do you need keep systems at, for example, better than 1 ms from each other? Do you need comparisons to a reference clock even when the Internet is down? Options to do better, if desired:

- Run your own NTP time service on the local network even closer to your nodes.
- Delegate to the local hypervisor. For example, the Google Cloud metadata service provides NTP, and the Azure (and Hyper-V) platform provides a PTP clock.